# Range of $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+\lfloor x \rfloor}$

Tags: functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I need to compute the range of: $$f(x) = \frac{1}{1+\lfloor x \rfloor}$$

Intuitively, the range is $\frac{1}{n}$, where $n \in \Bbb Z^*$, but I want to prove that this is the range of the function algebraically, using the fact that:

$\lfloor x \rfloor = m \iff m \le x \lt m+1 $

and $y= \frac{1}{1+\lfloor x \rfloor} \iff \forall \lfloor x \rfloor \ne -1 \implies   \lfloor x \rfloor = \frac {1 - y}{y} $

$\iff \frac {1 - y}{y} \le x \lt \frac {1 - y}{y} +1 , \forall y \ne 0$

But I don't know how to proceed.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the step $\lfloor x \rfloor =\dfrac{1-y}{y}$, you get that 
$$\frac{1-y}{y} \in \Bbb{Z}-\{-1\}.$$ 
Thus $\dfrac{1-y}{y}=k$, where $k \neq -1$. So $y=\frac{1}{k+1}$, where $k \neq -1$.

---

NOTE: Although I have to say that the above is just rehashing the obvious in a technical manner.